# FFMPEG - I'm trying to use ffmpeg to select all the .mp4 files in a folder and screenshot them with the file name as the image name

Tags: batch-file, video, ffmpeg, directory, screenshot

I have never dealt with .bat files before so this is new to me.

I'm trying to use **FFMPEG** to select all the **.mp4** files from a folder I place the **.bat** file in. Then to get it to screenshot every 30 minutes, and output the files with the input file name + image number in **JPEG**

This is what i came up with so far:

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf fps=1/1800 "${f%.mp4}.jpeg";done &&  cp  --copy-contents *.jpeg  ~*outputDirectory* && rm -R *.jpeg
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting the ?bash? code correctly this should do:

```
@Echo off
Set "JPEGdir=%UserProfile%\Outputdirectory"
for %%f in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%f" -vf fps=1/1800 "%JPEGdir%\%%~nf_%%d.jpeg"
```

- [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) variables need to be prefixed with `%%` in a batch (single `%` on the cmd line)
- instead of creating the JPEG in the source folder, copy and delete,  it's easier to create them straight in the destination folder by using the destination path and only the [filename without drive, path and extension %%~n](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) for the new name, appending the ffmpeg function to append a number `%d` (this percent sign has to be escaped with a second one)

**Edit** added folder creation:

```
@Echo off
Set "JPEGdir=%UserProfile%\Ouputdirectory"
for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
  If not Exist "%JPEGdir%\%%~nf" MkDir "%JPEGdir%\%%~nf"
  ffmpeg -i "%%f" -vf fps=1/1800 "%JPEGdir%\%%~nf\%%~nf_%%d.jpeg"
)
```

I derived the destination folder from your bash code, if you want the new folder in the current dir instead, just `set "JPEGdir=."`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388776/im-using-ffmpeg-in-bash-and-i-will-be-dealing-with-multiple-files would you have any idea how to do this??

Answer (score 1):

This is what i ended up with and it works perfectly now:

```
@Echo off

for %%i in (*.mp4) do (
    ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vf fps=1/1800 "%%~ni_%%d.jpeg"
)
```

Comment: Thank you though for the help @LotPings

Comment: Then you should consider to [accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).