# ffmpeg output to dynamically created folders

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, directory

My main aim is from the below code:

```
@Echo off

for %%i in (*.mp4) do (
ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vf fps=1/1800 "%%~ni_%%d.jpeg"
)
```

I want to be able to use the file name to create a new folder with said file name and store the images that will be screentshot in the folder.

*So basically have a separate folder created for each video file and it automatically naming the folder the same name as the file*

Comment: Firstly you haven't asked a question. Secondly what has this to do with bash?

Comment: Are you using the Windows shell?

Comment: You should delete this second unnecessary question. I'll change my answer in [the first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370521/ffmpeg-im-trying-to-use-ffmpeg-to-select-all-the-mp4-files-in-a-folder-and-s/43379270?noredirect=1#comment73838564_43379270).

Comment: Its being used in a windows shell yes.
I'm sorry if i havent explained myself enough but its just I'm very new to batch like only started having to use it a week ago

Comment: I have changed your question title and removed the confusing and incorrect reference to bash from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```bat
@echo off
for %%i in (*.mp4) do (if not exist "%%~ni\" MD "%%~ni"
    ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vf fps=1/1800 "%%~ni\%%~ni_%%d.jpeg")
```